# Comma in Time for microseconds in text file to be changed to decimal

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data in .txt file with single column and no header 
2017-09-05 15:55:44,958 - Alarm: Shelter Inverter - Distributor 
2017-09-05 15:55:44,966 - Alarm: Shelter Battery 2 - Interruption

**Desired Output:**
By using pandas read methods I want to achieve the output mentioned below.
col0                              
2017-09-05 15:55:44.958  Alarm: Shelter Inverter Distributor
2017-09-05 15:55:44.966  Alarm: Shelter Battery 2 Interruption

Previous attempts
**Using pd.read_csv** 
When I am importing the data dataset through pd.read_csv the output looks like this, even if I set decimal = ','. The output now has 2 columns separated by commas which I do not want.
col0        |        col1 
2017-09-05 15:55:44 | 958 - Alarm: Shelter Inverter - Distributor 
2017-09-05 15:55:44 | 966 - Alarm: Shelter Battery 2 - Interruption

**Using pd.read_table**
When I transform data via read_table I am getting the output as mentioned below.
even if I set decimal = ','.

col0 
2017-09-05 15:55:44,958 - Alarm: Shelter Inverter - Distributor
2017-09-05 15:55:44,966 - Alarm: Shelter Battery 2 - Interruption

Kindly do suggest any methods to get the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `str.replace`

**Ex:**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_table(filename, names=["S"])
print(df["S"].str.replace(",", "."))
```

**Output:**

```
0    2017-09-05 15:55:44.958 - Alarm: Shelter Inver...
1    2017-09-05 15:55:44.966 - Alarm: Shelter Batte...
Name: S, dtype: object
```

Comment: Works like a charm.. you are a legend Thanks